# encryption of an already existing database for SQLCipher

Tags: java, android, database, encryption, sqlcipher

I use an already existing database in my App (see also [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844735/sqldroid-and-encrypted-database)). I encrypted the database with a Java Application.
In my App I try to read the encrypted_database with the following code, but I get a **SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database**:

```
    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(mContext);
    SQLiteDatabase dataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, mPassword, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    String query = "Select distinct _id from TABLE";
    Cursor cursor = dataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cursor;
```

I already encrypted my database with SQLCipher and I also can read the data, so everything works fine.

The problem with SQLCipher and an already existing database is that I have to copy the complete unencrypted_database to an encrypted_database. This takes a long time when I do this on my phone.

My idea was: Write an Application in java that encrypts the database and take this encrypted_database in your app. This has the result that I just have to open the already existing encrypted_database in my app and no copying is required.

Now I wrote an Java Application (based on [2](http://cs.saddleback.edu/rwatkins/CS4B/Crypto/FileEncryptor.html),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption)) but there are still some questions related to SQLCipher and its design ([4](http://sqlcipher.net/design/)):

- how can I divide my database in database pages? In [4](http://sqlcipher.net/design/) a database page is just defined by its size (1024 bytes). But what I have to write into my encrypted_database file to say "database page starts" or "database page ends"
- is the salt and the random initialization vector (iv) part of the 1024 bytes?

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

      outFile_enc = new FileOutputStream(mFileNameEncrypted);
      outFile_dec = new FileOutputStream(mFileNameDecrypted);

      int keyLength = 256;
      // salt
      salt = new byte[16];
      Random rnd = new Random();
      rnd.nextBytes(salt);
      int iterations = 4000;

      SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
      KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(mPassWord.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, keyLength);
      SecretKey passwordKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
      key = new SecretKeySpec(passwordKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

      // creates a cipher and init it for encryption
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

      AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
      iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();

      encryptData(cipher);            
  }

  public static void encryptData(Cipher cipher) throws Exception{
      // File to encrypt
      inFile = new FileInputStream(mFileName);

      // unique random salt in the first 16 bytes of the file
      outFile_enc.write(salt);

      // Read file and encrypt its bytes
      byte[] input  = new byte[64];
      int bytesRead;
      while((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1){
      byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
      if(output != null)
          outFile_enc.write(output);
      }

      byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
      if(output != null)
          outFile_enc.write(output);
      // random initialization vector is stored at the end of a page
      outFile_enc.write(iv);

      inFile.close();
      outFile_enc.flush();
      outFile_enc.close();    
  }
  ```

I appreciate every help/idea/comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe approach of trying to recreate a SQLCipher file from scratch is not advised. The format is more complicated than what you are doing, and it will be non-trivial reproduce a valid SQLCipher file. Instead, you should just use the [SQLCipher command line program](http://sqlcipher.net/introduction/) to [encrypt your database](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export) for distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I saw the SQLCipher API, but I didn't understand how to solve my problem. Your answer helped me to get an idea :). I'll try it next time.